# Как проверить строку на допустимые символы?

Tags: preg_match, php

Здравствуйте, Уважаемые ХэшКодеры!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить в php строку. Нужно, чтобы она содержала только буквы английского алфавита и цифры.

Спасибо большое человеческое!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]]+$/", "1234234efshdkjfhweuir29dakhjkHKKGHK"))
    /* do_something */
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!